# How to create autocomplete text box or typeahead in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have currently started working in symfony2 framework and I want a field where I can type a name and get suggestions. The suggestions will be from database.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [PUGXAutoCompleterBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle)

Take a look at the [doc](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

Comment: It is not working. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: is the  approach not valid for your needed or you have same problem with it?

Comment: hi @John what problem do you have with this bundle? Have you tried somethjing other?

Comment: I have used  $results = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT name FROM products where name like '%".$q."%'"); in searchBookAction(). In  $q I am passing the parameters. Now I am passing $results  to twig but I am not able to loop through it

Comment: And I am confused on how do I insert this  $('#product_book').autocompleter({url_list: '/book_search', url_get: '/book_get/'}); in my code